# Displaying query to jTable

Tags: java, swing, hibernate

I got my form (made using Design option in netbeans). In source code of that form I got method:

```
public void wyswietlWybrane(List<Osoba> osoby) {   
        DefaultTableModel model2 = (DefaultTableModel) listaOsob.getModel();
        String zainteresowania = "";
        for (Osoba a : osoby){
        List zainteresowania1 = a.getZainteresowania();         
        for (Iterator iterator2 = zainteresowania1.iterator(); iterator2.hasNext();){
                Zainteresowania nazwa = (Zainteresowania) iterator2.next();
                zainteresowania =  (zainteresowania + (nazwa.getZainteresowanie() + ".  " + "<br>")); 
            }   
        zainteresowania = "<html>" + zainteresowania + "</html>";
        model2.addRow(new Object[]{a.getImie(), a.getNazwisko(), a.getEmail(), a.getTelefon(), zainteresowania});     
        zainteresowania = "";
        }
    }
```

and it works perfectly, but when I am trying to move that method to e.g PersonDao like that:

```
public void wyswietlWybrane(List<Osoba> osoby) {   
        Kwestionariusz temp = new Kwestionariusz();
        DefaultTableModel model2 = (DefaultTableModel) temp.listaOsob.getModel();
        String zainteresowania = "";
        for (Osoba a : osoby){
        List zainteresowania1 = a.getZainteresowania();         
        for (Iterator iterator2 = zainteresowania1.iterator(); iterator2.hasNext();){
                Zainteresowania nazwa = (Zainteresowania) iterator2.next();
                zainteresowania =  (zainteresowania + (nazwa.getZainteresowanie() + ".  " + "<br>")); 
            }   
        zainteresowania = "<html>" + zainteresowania + "</html>";
        model2.addRow(new Object[]{a.getImie(), a.getNazwisko(), a.getEmail(), a.getTelefon(), zainteresowania});     
        zainteresowania = "";
        }
    }
```

it doesnt work, it doesnt update my jTable.

Kwestionariusz is my form file.

```
List <ListaZainteresowan> listaZainteresowan = jListaZainteresowan.getSelectedValuesList();


List<Osoba> osoby = temp.wyszukajOsoby(listaZainteresowan, imieField.getText(), nazwiskoField.getText());


wyswietlWybrane(osoby);
```

in WyszukajOsoby there is query to db and:

```
for (Osoba osoba : osoby) {
    Hibernate.initialize(osoba.zainteresowania);
    }
```

so it can work without session in WyswietlWybrane.

How can I make this method works in DAO file? How can I get model in correct way cuz when I pass it by argument then it works BUT I dont want to pass it via argument.

@edit

doesnt anyone know?

Comment: Please provide a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), if you want to get answer for your question. Probably you find the answer by yourself, when you write the MVCE.

Comment: Well when I have this method in file named Kwestionariusz (which is also my form file, whole desing is here) then creating model using `DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) listaOsob.getModel();`
works fine what means that my selected people from Query appears in my jTable. (listaOsob is jTable)

but when I move my method to other DAO file I have make my model like this:

`Kwestionariusz temp = new Kwestionariusz();
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) temp.listaOsob.getModel()`

and then my jTable doesnt update, it remains empty.
When I pass created model via argument when

Comment: when method is in DAO file, and I use that passed model then it works again, but I dont want to pass model via argument. What I want is to create model inside method and use in the way so it will update my jTable